# Pandas pivot based on two columns (multi index)

Tags: python, pandas

i have a DataFrame:

```
u_id    date        social_interaction_type_id  Total_Count
4       2018-08-19  4                           5
4       2018-08-24  2                           3
4       2018-08-21  1                           4
```

**i want to pivot the DataFrame based on u_id and date.**

**so the result should look like something like this:**

```
u_id    date        4       2       1
4       2018-08-19  5       nan     nan
4       2018-08-24  nan     3       nan
4       2018-08-21  nan     nan     4
```

**my code attempt:**

```
df.pivot(index = ['u_id','date'] , columns='social_interaction_type_id',values='Total_Count')
```

**error:**

```
ValueError: Length of passed values is 8803, index implies 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use alternative solution with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.set_index(['u_id','date','social_interaction_type_id'])['Total_Count']
       .unstack()
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
   u_id        date    1    2    4
0     4  2018-08-19  NaN  NaN  5.0
1     4  2018-08-21  4.0  NaN  NaN
2     4  2018-08-24  NaN  3.0  NaN
```

If duplicated in first 2 columns is necessary use aggregate function `mean`, `sum` like:

```
print (df)
   u_id        date  social_interaction_type_id  Total_Count
0     4  2018-08-19                           4            5 <- 4  2018-08-19 
1     4  2018-08-19                           6            4 <- 4  2018-08-19 
2     4  2018-08-24                           2            3
3     4  2018-08-21                           1            4


df2 = (df.groupby(['u_id','date','social_interaction_type_id'])['Total_Count']
       .mean() 
       .unstack()
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

Or:

```
df2 = (df.pivot_table(index=['u_id','date'],columns='social_interaction_type_id', values='Total_Count')
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

---

```
print (df2)
   u_id        date    1    2    4    6
0     4  2018-08-19  NaN  NaN  5.0  4.0
1     4  2018-08-21  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2     4  2018-08-24  NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: is it possible to rename the columns, i.e. A, B, C instead of 1, 2, 4? I used pivot_table.

Comment: @Jason it is possible by `df2.rename(columns={1:'A',2:'B',3:'C'})`

Comment: Thank you. I asked because I have hundreds of columns and would like to change it automatically to texts but I guess that should be another question.

Answer (score 8):

[`pd.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), for reasons unknown to me, don't work with a list of values for `index`. As per the docs, optional `index` must be a *string* or *object*. A workaround is to use [`pd.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) with `aggfunc='first'`:

```
res = df.pivot_table(index=['u_id', 'date'], columns='social_interaction_type_id',
                     values='Total_Count', aggfunc='first').reset_index()

print(res)

social_interaction_type_id  u_id        date    1    2    4
0                              4  2018-08-19  NaN  NaN  5.0
1                              4  2018-08-21  4.0  NaN  NaN
2                              4  2018-08-24  NaN  3.0  NaN
```

Comment: Passing multiple indices to `pivot` was added in 1.1.0; currently this is [highlighted in the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)