# unstack 2 columns one with column names and the other with values into multiple columns-pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the "Name" column contains data that should make up column names and "Value" column has the corresponding values:

```
Id      set Name            Value
6050    256 Main_id         5677002
6050    256 Secondary_id    34248
6050    256 Quantity         6
6050    256 warranty Date    4/1/2018
6050    256 Type             AB12
6050    256 Value            crypt
6050    256 Category         DFR
6050    256 Capacity         100
6050    256 Type             AB13
6050    256 Value            crypt
6050    256 Category         BAS
6050    256 Capacity         500
6050    256 Start Date       4/1/2022
6050    256 End Date         1/31/2023
123     456 Main_id          123456789
123     456 Secondary_id     101112131
123     456 Quantity         4
123     456 Type             AB12
123     456 Value            crypt
123     456 Category         DFR
123     456 Capacity         100
123     456 Quantity          5
123     456 warranty Date     4/1/2017
123     456 Type              MAC12
123     456 Value             crypt
123     456 Category          DFR
123     456 Capacity          100
123     456 Start Date        4/1/2022
123     456 End Date          1/31/2023
897     956 Main_id           gy4567890
897     956 Secondary_id      ky234248
897     956 Quantity          6
897     956 Type              MAB13
897     956 Value             nocl
897     956 Category          gcl
897     956 Capacity          100
897     956 Start Date        4/1/2022
897     956 End Date          1/31/2023
```

Output wanted:
[image]
For each set of ids and start and end dates, it will always start with "Quantity" and end in "Capacity" and in between one or more "Type" will be present. wherever data is missing it should be left blank. And where more than one "Type" present the "Quantity" (and/or "Warranty Date") will repeat.

This doesn't work with this dataframe.

```
df_.pivot_table(index=["Id", "set"], 
                      columns='Name', 
                      values='Value', 
                      aggfunc=', '.join).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Any help or suggestions is much appreciated.

Comment: added a solution, does it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it

creating a temp column using assign to break the duplication error in pivot, and dropping the column afterwards

```
df.assign(
    dup=df.groupby(['Id', 'Name']).cumcount()
).pivot(
    index=['Id','set','dup'], 
    columns='Name', 
    values='Value').reset_index().drop(columns='dup')
```

[image]

to fill in the null values with the previous values for the same id you can do as follows

```
df2=df.assign(
    dup=df.groupby(['Id', 'Name']).cumcount()
).pivot(
    index=['Id','set','dup'], 
    columns='Name', 
    values='Value').reset_index() 
df2.groupby('Id').fillna(method='ffill').drop(columns='dup')
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting a value error with .pivot: ValueError: Length of passed values is 38, index implies 3

Comment: what is your DF index? i used the data you provided and the screenshot is a resut of the solution.  check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701012/pandas-pivot-based-on-two-columns-multi-index

Comment: So this worked for me: df.set_index(['Id','set','dup']).pivot(columns="Name")['Value'].reset_index()\
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
But for the first Quantity-Type there is no warranty date, it is pulling that from the 2nd Quantity-Type. Any idea how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I meant for the filling code part-set 456 first Quantity-Type there is no warranty date, it is pulling that from the 2nd Quantity-Type. Any idea how to fix it? Thanks.